# Virtual environment with git

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

Recently I found out about the importance of git and therefor started to experiment with it, however I ran into some problems when trying to implement it in a python project on boids. The project directory looks like this:

```
Boids/
├─ .venv/
│  ├─ ...
├─ .vscode/
│  ├─ ...
├─ __pycache__/
│  ├─ ...
├─ main.py
├─ boid.py
```

I don't think I want to track everything that happens in the `.venv`, `.vscode` and `__pycache__` folders through git (right?). Does anyone know how I could arrange this? Also, when uploading the project to GitHub through git Bash, should I include these folders there too? If so, does this work as I guess I would have `.gititgnore` files in the named folders.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens in `.vscode` makes sense to put in the repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not include those folders because they are dependent on your system and will most likely not work for other people (e.g., Mac vs Windows). Yes, a `.gitignore` (Note the spelling) is the way to go. There are many examples out there. Often when you create a Git Repo you can select to include one. However, it sounds like you already have a full `git` configured so it's best to push to an empty GitHub repo. Here's one that I often start with for Python projects: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense why that would be problematic. I then have one more question. When I push my project to my GitHub repo with the `.gitignore` configured, does it then completely exclude these files from GitHub (which would be what I want in this case), or does it just not record the changes I make to them?

Comment: When you include the `.gitignore` it should prevent including those files so that a simple `git add .` will _include other files only_. I would do a `git status` after the `git add .` to see what will be included. If you forget to include something, just do a `git reset .`, adjust your `.gitignore` and try again. I rarely use `git add .` because that can be very dangerous. I often add individual files. As long as you don't `git commit` you can adjust as needed. Good luck!

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. Thanks for the advice and for taking the time to help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll pay attention to that.

Comment: @astrochun you can have specific `.gitignore` in subfolders, if you don't want to clutter the main `.gitignore`